# How to install a pre-built npm package from a Chocolatey package?

Tags: npm, chocolatey

In our company we need to install a pre-built [NPM](https://npmjs.org/) package (Karma) on Windows, and we would like to do so via [Chocolatey](https://github.com/chocolatey/chocolatey) for maximum simplicity. The main reason we want to install the prebuilt NPM, as opposed to from source, is that some of Karma's dependencies won't build on some of our employees' machines.

How should we install the pre-built NPM package from a Chocolatey package? Our impression so far regarding generating the pre-built NPM package itself, is that one should install the source package via NPM and zip up the results.

Comment: Prebuilt? Hmmm, not fully sure how you would do that. At least not without including the prebuilt items and placing them in the proper directory on install (using chocolatey powershell install script). But it's kind of short-circuiting what NPM does (and could be brittle if NPM changes). Wouldn't it be better to fix the employees' machines so it would work properly?

Comment: @ferventcoder My co-workers would have to install Visual C++ due to a dependency that needs compiling, and that won't happen (we're a C# shop). One of my co-workers went with the pre-built approach (manually) and he thinks that's the way to go.

Comment: Interesting. Most places I've worked we just install Visual Studio with almost everything on (aside from a few things like the Obfuscator that comes with it). It's interesting that NPM doesn't install something it needs to install the package?

Comment: If you guys are fine with keeping those pre-built packages off of chocolatey.org for now, then that's probably a good approach for your company. :)

Comment: @ferventcoder It will be private to us, yes. I was also surprised that Visual C++ was required, but my colleague reproduced the issue for me and as they say, seeing is believing :)

Answer (score 0):

This is more an issue with having pre-built packages with NPM than it is with chocolatey building them.

Ruby uses DevKit on Windows to build out native gems. It handles the compilation of the gem as it installs it. What solution does NPM have in this case?

One could take a dependency on MinGW and build the NPM package with gcc (or use VC++ as you mentioned in the comments).

However having the pre-built NPM set into the chocolatey package as a solution wouldn't be using an official binary, so unless it is coming from the guy who created it (Karma in this case), I don't think you will find other users would like it on the community feed.

To me it seems like this falls with NPM to have something similar to DevKit.